# php make html table rows equal

Tags: php, jquery, html, foreach

I am getting data from a my database. There is a admin panel also where people can add data to the database. The data gets on the page but some of the rows(`<tr>`) have less table data tags(`<td>`) than others. thus the table is not justified. Is there a way to add empty `<td>` to rows that need them? I have tried everything but i can't figure it out.

Picture on how the table looks at the moment:
[image]
The green numbers are the total sum of points but it's not clear because the table rows are jagged. How to fix tis?

If there is a jQuery solution that's also fine.

my code:

```
echo "<table class=\"zebra1\">";
echo "<th>N. </th>" . "<th>Team name: </th>" . "<th colspan=\"5\">Points: </th>" . "<th>Sum: </th>";
$numbering =1;
$query2 = $db->prepare("SELECT pisteet_1 As PIY, pisteet_2 as PIK, nimi As NIM, opisto As OPI, pisteet.kaupunki_id As KA FROM
 pisteet INNER JOIN joukkueet ON joukkueet.id = pisteet.team_id INNER JOIN oppilaitokset ON oppilaitokset.opisto_id = joukkueet.opisto_id ORDER BY team_id ASC");
$query2->execute();
$results = $query2->fetchAll();

$tableD = array();
foreach ($results as $key) {
    $tableD[$key['NIM']][] = array('PIY'=>$key['PIY'],'PIK'=>$key['PIK'],'KA'=>$key['KA'], 'OPI'=>$key['OPI']);
}

foreach($tableD as $teamN=>$values2){
    //Echoing the Team name
    echo "<tr class=\"all " . $values2[0]['KA'] . "\">";
    echo "<td>" . $numbering . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $teamN ."<span>" . $values2[0]['OPI'] ."</span></td>";
    $sum1=0;
    $sum2=0;

    //Echoing the points
    foreach($values2 as $v2){
        echo "<td class=\"points\">" . $v2['PIY'] . "/" . $v2['PIK'] .  "</td>";
        $sum1 +=$v2['PIY'];
        $sum2 +=$v2['PIK'];
    }
    //Echoing the total sum of points
    echo '<td class="Sum">'.$sum1.'/'.$sum2."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $numbering ++;
}
echo '</table>';
```

I have a variable named: `$colspancalculated` that has the longest row: at the moment it stores the value 5.

Comment: Is the number of columns you'll have fixed or dynamic? If it's dynamic, you'll probably need to loop through your result set before you output it so you can find the largest number of columns (or if its fixed, define that size yourself) then on your inner foreach, you either output the td with contents or output a blank cell in its place

Comment: @scrowler They are dynamic. I already have done that `$colspancalculated` has the largest number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a fixed number of columns (I assume this because you've got a colspan on your table header cell), you need to output the td elements as you are doing, or output blank cells if the records don't exist.

Consider something like this instead of your foreach:

```
// Echoing the points - as you mention in your comment, you've calculated
// the maximum column size as $colspancalculated - so you that as your upper limit
for($i = 0; $i < $colspancalculated; $i++) {
    if(!isset($values2[$i]['PIY'])) {
        // This record doesn't exist! Output a blank cell
        echo '<td></td>';
        continue;
    }

    // Otherwise, output the cell and do your calculations
    echo '<td class="points">' . $values2[$i]['PIY'] . '/' . $values2[$i]['PIK'] . '</td>';
    $sum1 += $values2[$i]['PIY'];
    $sum2 += $values2[$i]['PIK'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `foreach` loop, use a `for` loop -- or, since you have to work with an iterator, anyway, just do:

```
$i = $numberOfColumnsLeftAtThisPointInYourScript
foreach($values2 as $v2){
    echo "<td class=\"points\">" . $v2['PIY'] . "/" . $v2['PIK'] .  "</td>";
    $sum1 +=$v2['PIY'];
    $sum2 +=$v2['PIK'];
    $i--;
}
while($i > 0){
    echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    $i--;
}
```

Comment: @scrowler This does add new `<td>` but every row gets them. I have added a picture of this.

Comment: @Pullapooh this isn't my solution, I simply edited it to fix a syntax error

Comment: Yeah, try his while I wrap my mind around why that happens ---

Comment: @rm-vanda check the edit ($colspancalculated) hope this helps.